# Is it possible to have different size in terms of pixel and meter?

Tags: c#, output

I have a colormap graph output. I tried to check cell size and found they don't match with data. To find the problem, cells size were determine to be equal. Interestingly, it was revealed that despite of equal cell thickness I saw unequal cell size.

This is a picture of the output: 
http://s27.postimg.org/erq0pcqgj/Fluid_FD_Temperature0000.png
[image]

Thickness of two vertical lines is not equal but numerically and other outputs show equal amount.

What is the reason of this conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of changing integers to decimal values(cell dimension to pixels).

[image] It can be solve by increasing pixel numbers of each picture.